# Country codes list - C#

Tags: c#, internationalization, country-codes

I have a string which I need to verify if it's a Country code. The culture is German. Is there any method that I can call to get a list of Country codes in a German culture without having to type out all the 274 (?) codes myself?

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you say "country code" I assume you mean the two-letter code as in [ISO 3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements). Then you can use the RegionInfo constructor to check if your string is a correct code.

```
string countryCode = "de";
try {
    RegionInfo info = new RegionInfo(countryCode);
}
catch (ArgumentException argEx)
{
    // The code was not a valid country code
}
```

You could also, as you state in your question, check if it is a valid country code for the german language. Then you just pass in a specific culture name together with the country code.

```
string language = "de";
string countryCode = "de";
try {
    RegionInfo info = new RegionInfo(string.Format("{0}-{1}", language, countryCode));
}
catch (ArgumentException argEx)
{
    // The code was not a valid country code for the specified language
}
```

Comment: It turns out the German health insurance uses a different system of naming countries. Country code sizes varied from 1-3 chars. Thanks for the help though! – Teja 0 secs ago

Comment: Wow..that's really odd. If it was only three letters I would have guessed it to be ISO 3166-1 Alpha 3 that uses three letters for the country code (DEU for German).

Comment: RegionInfo does not confirm completely with ISO 3166. There are a few exceptions to this list, for instance Cyprys (CY) is on the ISO 3166 list, but is not recognized by RegionInfo.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is a misuse of the `ArgumentException` thrown by the constructor. You're not really using the `RegionInfo` or the `ArgumentException` instances, which makes the code's purpose very unclear.

Instead, get a list of all specific cultures, then search through the regions of those cultures to find a match on your ISO 3166 alpha-2 code:

```
bool IsCountryCodeValid(string countryCode)
{
    return CultureInfo
        .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(culture => new RegionInfo(culture.LCID))
                .Any(region => region.TwoLetterISORegionName == countryCode);
}
```

Or specifically, for your problem:

```
bool IsValidGermanCountryCode(string countryCode)
{
    return CultureInfo
        .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Where(culture => culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "de")
                .Select(culture => new RegionInfo(culture.LCID))
                    .Any(region => region.TwoLetterISORegionName == countryCode);
}
```

Comment: Obviously this uses LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need countries/regions, you can make use of the RegionInfo class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using `RegionInfo` to check for a valid ISO code.  It will return a region if the code you supply is valid AND it is a supported region, but it will not do this for all valid ISO 3166 codes.

See here for a fuller explanation: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9a8bc14-d571-4702-91a6-1b80da239009/question-of-regioninfo-and-region-cy

`RegionInfo` will work fine for Europe, but there are several African countries that aren't validated with this method (e.g. Uganda).

Answer (score 2):

You can use my nuget package [`Nager.Country`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Country). There is a lot of additional information available for each country. For more information please visit the [Github project](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Country)

```
PM> install-package Nager.Country
```

```cs
var countryCode = "de";
ICountryProvider countryProvider = new CountryProvider();
var countryInfo = countryProvider.GetCountry(countryCode);
if (countryInfo != null)
{
    //country exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://cldr.unicode.org/ - common standard multilanguage database include country list  and other localizable data.