# Country list for phone number

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop an app for Windows Phone 8.1. My project requires the user to input the his phone number, so i was wondering if there's a built in class within the .net framework that will give me the option to provide the user the list of all countries, like how you sign up for something, and there's a list of counties the user would need to select from, and provide his phone number, depending on this country he's from. If there's some provisioning within the framework, can u help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Country codes list - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324048/country-codes-list-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

A simple constant string array should suffice, although it might take up some place. I would recommend saving a text file where each row represent a different country and then read that file and parse each row as a item whenever you need to use it.

**Easy way, cluttered code**

```
string[] countries = new string[5] {"Example", "Example", "Example", "Example", "Example"};
```

**Another way, managable code**

```
string countryList;
//read from a included text / xml / json file to countryList
foreach (string line in new LineReader(() => new StringReader(text)))
{
    //line is your country
}
```

Comment: So does it mean I will have to enter each country manually? Or is there a class within the .net framework that can pull that up for me?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson to clarify, this is a "manual" approach, not a .net one. There is no included way that I know of. "Manual" since there are many copy paste lists of countries, with which you could write the code shown above to use that list.